# Batch File To Iterate Over All Combinations Of External Hard Drives

Tags: batch-file

I have a number of external hard drives containing backups of my library folders and like to keep then all in sync using Robocopy. So my question is how can I iterate over all combinations of external drives in a batch file?

e.g. Three external hard drives containing the following library folders
E:\Libraries, G:\Libraries and N:\Libraries

1. If E:\Libraries Then robocopy  G:\ Libraries to N:\Libraries
2. If G:\Libraries Then robocopy  E:\ Libraries to N:\Libraries
3. If N:\Libraries Then robocopy  E:\ Libraries to G:\Libraries

and so on for all the possible combinations of the connected external hard drives

Comment: `for %%a in (E G N) do echo %%a:\Libraries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy option is to propagate changes along the disks first in one direction (lower to higher drives) and then in the oposite direction.

```
        Drives          A:      B:      C:      D:      E:
-------------------------------------------------------------
        Data inside     A       B       C       D       E
-------------------------------------------------------------
copy operations
> 1                     A   >   AB      C       D       E
> 2                     A       AB   >  ABC     D       E
> 3                     A       AB      ABC   > ABCD    E
> 4                     A       AB      ABC     ABCD  > ABCDE
-------------------------------------------------------------
< 5                     A       AB      ABC     ABCDE < ABCDE
< 6                     A       AB      ABCDE < ABCDE   ABCDE
< 7                     A       ABCDE < ABCDE   ABCDE   ABCDE
< 8                     ABCDE < ABCDE   ABCDE   ABCDE   ABCDE
```

Wich can be done as

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "librariesFolder=\Libraries"

    set nDrives=0
    rem Enumerate available disks 
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:=" %%a in ('
        wmic logicaldisk get name /value
    ') do (
        rem Check if drive can be accessed and contains libraries folder
        >nul 2>nul vol %%a: && if exist "%%a:%librariesFolder%" (
            set /a nDrives+=1
            set "drive!nDrives!=%%a"
        )
    )
    if %nDrives% lss 2 (
        echo Not enough drives found to sync
        goto :eof
    )

    rem Propagate changes from fist disk to last
    set "s=" & for /l %%t in (1 1 %nDrives%) do (
        if defined s for %%s in (!s!) do (
            echo robocopy "!drive%%s!:%librariesFolder%\." "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\." /s
        )
        set "s=%%t"
    )

    rem Propagate changes from last disk to first
    set "s=" & for /l %%t in (%nDrives% -1 1) do (
        if defined s for %%s in (!s!) do (
            echo robocopy "!drive%%s!:%librariesFolder%\." "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\." /s
        )
        set "s=%%t"
    )
```

Note that the `robocopy` operations are prefixed with an `echo` command to avoid any changes. If the output to console is correct then remove the `echo` to execute the copy operations

**edited** to answer to comments - To exclude some folders not present in target, you can try with something like

```dos
if defined s for %%s in (!s!) do ( 
    set "excludeFolders="
    for %%x in ("Camera Movies" "Documents" "Downloads") do (
        if not exist "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\%%~x\" (
            set excludeFolders=!excludeFolders! %%x
        )
    )
    if defined excludeFolders set excludeFolders=/XD !excludeFolders!
    robocopy.exe "!drive%%s!:%librariesFolder%\." "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\." /S !excludeFolders! 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for help it is working well. I am now, however trying to expand the batch file to work with some of my smaller hard drives in making it exclude certain folders if they don't exist in the target folder. Below is what I have done so far but I would appreciated some further help to get the exclude folders syntax working correctly with robocopy

Comment: if defined s for %%s in (!s!) do (
         if not exist "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\Camera Movies" (
  Set ExcludeFolder1="Camera Movies" 
  )
  if not exist "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\Documents" (
  Set ExcludeFolder2=Documents 
  )
  if not exist "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\Downloads" (
  Set ExcludeFolder3=Downloads 
  )
  Set %ExcludeFolders%=XD %ExcludeFolder1% %ExcludeFolder2% %ExcludeFolder3%
 robocopy.exe "!drive%%s!:%librariesFolder%\." "!drive%%t!:%librariesFolder%\." /S %ExcludeFolders% 
        )
        set "s=%%t"

Comment: @Marsi63, answer updated. Your approach included some errors in the `set ExcludeFolders` (wrong percents, missing `/`) variable . I hope the included version is a little more flexible.

Comment: Nearly there can you help me a couple of things still not working in my example below?

D:\Libraries contains
Camera Movies
Documents

E:\Libraries contains
Documents
Downloads

1. For some reason when copying from first disk (D) to last (E) %excludeFolders% doesn't contain Camera Movies and yet it is not in the target folder (E). It is, however, correctly excluded when copying back from E to D.
2. Camera Movies needs to be quoted as it contains a space in the %excludeFolders% variable

Comment: @Marsi63, Sorry, my fault, just a copy/paste problem. It should be `!excludeFolders!`. Corrected in answer.

Comment: @ MC ND One last thing as camera movies contains a space how do I get quotes around it in the  !excludeFolders! variable

Comment: @Marsi63, the code is concatenating `%%x` inside `excludedFolder`. As the values being iterated (`for %%x`) are quoted, they are added with quotes.

Comment: @ MC ND
Apologies I was using MSG * to provide me with a popup message while testing rather than using echo. This wasn't displaying the quotes. Thanks once again for all of your help on this.